Plotly KDE in histogram
I can create a histogram in Plotly like this:
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
import plotly.express as px

data = px.data.tips()["tip"]

ff.create_distplot([data], group_labels=["Tip"])


However, ff.create_distplot is deprecated. The docs recommend using px.histogram.
I tried:
px.histogram(
    x=data,
    marginal="rug",
)

However, it did not produce a graph with KDE (the curve):

How do I fix it?

I checked and found comments from the developer in the Plotly community. There does not seem to be an option for density estimation yet. So the best answer at the moment may be to add the histnorm option to px.histgram() and add it in the form of reusing KDE data in ff.create_displot().
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

data = px.data.tips()["tip"]
kde = ff.create_distplot([data], group_labels=['Tip'], show_hist=False)

fig = px.histogram(
    x=data,
    marginal="rug",
    histnorm='probability density',
)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=kde.data[0].x,
    y=kde.data[0].y,
    mode='lines',
    marker=dict(color='#636efa'),
    showlegend=False,
    name='Tip',
    yaxis='y')
)
     
fig.show()


